# EmberJS: Get PDF in a new window tab from server using link

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to use the default behavior of a browser to open a pdf file in a new tab using Ember. 
I'm not using Ember-Data and as a server side resource I'm using Python. So I set the proxy address on startup of Ember to point to server side address.

I built a route page and I have a link to open my PDF file in the browser like

```
<a href="/path/apps/list.pdf?list=current" target="_blank">Open</a>
```

And the server Python resource returns a pdf:

```
@get("/list.pdf") 
@params(C.String("list"))
def get_list_pdf(list):   
    //some code to build the pdf string 
    Response(pdf_string, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'})
```

I tried it in an application without ember to access the resource from a link and it is fine. But with Ember I'm not able to do that.

I got this error: **Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError: /path/apps/list.pdf?list=current ember.debug.js:4914**

Any suggestions how I can achieve that?

Comment: It definitely should work. Whats the problem? Whats not working?

Comment: I got a new blank tab without getting the PDF file. Ember runs on localhost:4200 and I point to myIp:6969 on startup ember serve --proxy=http://myip:6969. The rest of normal rest calls like returning a json object are fine. I'm not transiting to a new route for the pdf file, I just want to open in with the browser.

Comment: I updated the description with the error I'm getting

Comment: Hm, have you tried a link starting with `http://`?

Comment: Yes I tried the following: http://localhost:4200/path/apps/list.pdf?list=current but no luck. The only thing which is working is to access it directly e.g. http://myip:6969/path/apps/list.pdf?list=current. But what is the point of using it this way? I don't like adding the domain to my code. What if i change it in the future.

Comment: It is like attempting URL transition to /path/apps/list.pdf?list=current instead of accessing the resource from server. That it because I'm using a link. I also tried window.open() with an action on a button but also no luck.

Comment: window.open with a path starting with `http://` is definitely working, because thats what I use. Is your `.pdf` in your public server or should the request get proxied to your backend? Because later one will maybe not work from within the development server.

Comment: For now the request get proxied to my backend locally. In the future I will use a public server. But, I found a different solution of creating a new route and add into its template the <object> element and I got the pdf passing as an argument the url and render the pdf into the object element.

Comment: You can't use a relative path in this case, you have to use the full url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to my problem I created a new route and I added to its template the  html object element. I added also a {{link-to 'the route' (query-params url='the url') }} to transit to the route to render the PDF.

The template.hbs

```
<object data={{url}} type='application/pdf' />
```